# Model Framework for ASP .NET / MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csla

I have been using the CSLA framework for couple of years now for windows applications. With ASP .NET MVC / AJAX / jQuery out now, would there be any use for the CSLA framework (which is strongly Object Oriented ) in web apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely you would.  CSLA is used for building your business logic layers; which ui medium you use doesn't really matter.  Yes there are some nice new tools and patterns out there for building and controlling web ui, but the plumbing that CSLA gives you for creating a business framework is second to few (if any).  CSLA is not about the UI, its about all the logic the ui is using.

Answer (score 3):

In a recent episode of .Net Rocks, Rocky Lhotka talks about the upcoming version ov CSLA will have MVC support.  They just added silverlight support, and, afaik, it works well with web forms as well.

http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=387